# (node:12452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js

getting error in the first line of json file.

```
 {
          "name": "node-api",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "index.js",
          "scripts": {
            "dev" : "npx nodemon index"
          },
          "keywords": [],
          "author": "",
          "license": "ISC",
          "dependencies": {
            "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
            "express": "^4.17.1",
            "mongoose": "^5.13.5"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
          }
        }
```

Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any details.(768)

Comment: Do you have any VSCode extensions enabled?

Comment: Nope bro no extension..

Comment: I'd suggest searching different parts of your error. Is there a proxy between you and schemastore.org? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36197